# FeatherJS error message : Calling populate(target, options) is now DEPRECATED

Tags: node.js, mongoose, runtime-error

i'm using Feathers JS framework and mongoose library to create web services, but when i want to launch my project i get this error message :

```
 Mongoose option.lean is false. Use hook.results.toObject() to convert the results to JS objects
Calling populate(target, options) is now DEPRECATED and will be removed in the future
```

code :

```
  var mongooseService = require('feathers-mongoose');

 app.use('user', mongooseService({
     name: 'user',
     Model: require('./../models/user'),
     id: 'cuid'
   }))

   .use('post', mongooseService({
     name: 'post',
     Model: require('./../models/post'),
   }))

 var getLastPost = function() {
   return app.service('post').find({
     query: {
       "status": {
         $in: [0, 1, 2]
       },
       $select: ['version', '_id']
     }
   });
 };
 app.service('post')
   .before(getLastPost)
   .after(hooks.populate('user', {
     service: 'user'
   }))
```

is there any thing i have to do to remove this error messages ?

Comment: can you post your mongoose query here

Comment: i updated my  post.

Comment: Ahmed, I have updated an answer please let me know if it will resolve your issue or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the second message error :

```
 var auk = require('feathers-hooks-common');
   var populate = function(serviceName,name,parentFieldName,childFieldName){
   return auk.populate({
      schema: {
      include: {
        service: serviceName,
        nameAs: name,
        parentField: parentFieldName,
        childField: childFieldName
      }
    }
  })
  }
  app.service('post').hooks({
    after: {all: populate("user","user","user","_id")}
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is required to add lean property when you define service.

```
 var mongooseService = require('feathers-mongoose');

 app.use('user', mongooseService({
     "name": 'user',
     "Model": require('./../models/user'),
     "id": 'cuid',
     "lean": true
   }))

   .use('post', mongooseService({
     "name": 'post',
     "Model": require('./../models/post'),
     "lean": true
   }))

 var getLastPost = function() {
   return app.service('post').find({
     query: {
       "status": {
         $in: [0, 1, 2]
       },
       $select: ['version', '_id']
     }
   });
 };
 app.service('post')
   .before(getLastPost)
   .after(hooks.populate('user', {
     create: function(hook, next) {
        hook.result = hook.result.toObject();
        next();
     },
     service: 'user'
   }))
```

Comment: thank's for your answer but "lean": true ==> return a plain objects instead of Mongoose models, that's why im using lean:false

Comment: can you try discriminators?

Comment: there should be use feathers-hook

Comment: @AHmédNet I have updated an answer and please look into the last app.service("post") I add to create property and convert hook result to object and reassigned. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @AHmédNet did you find a way or not?

Comment: it's work to resolve the first messge error, thank's, now, it still the second one : Calling populate(target, options) is now DEPRECATED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172062/discussion-between-dipak-chavda-and-ahmed-net).